# Windows 8.1 keyboard shortcut to move a Store app to another monitor

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, multiple-monitors, windows-8.1

Back in the good ol' Windows 8 days, there was a keyboard shortcut to move a Windows Store app to another monitor (<kbd>Ctrl+PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+PgDn</kbd> IIRC). On Windows 8.1, nothing seems to work. Is there still a shortcut?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd> move across monitors. Hope that helps!